# Origen de la expresión "menos mal"

Tags: etimología, modismos

Acabo de caer en la cuenta de que "menos mal" es una expresión que, si la leemos literalmente, es de esas como "no hay de qué" o "buenos días" en las que parece que originalmente la expresión era parte de una frase más larga que se ha perdido con el tiempo.

Así, una frase como

> Es una suerte que hayas venido.

parece completa. Pero en

> Menos mal que has venido.

es como si faltara algo, como si fuese algo en plan "ahora que has venido el mal es menos mal".

El diccionario la define así:

> **[menos mal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NyEUGaa#7HW1YyN)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. U. para indicar alivio porque no ocurre o no ha ocurrido algo malo que se temía, o porque ocurre o ha ocurrido algo bueno con lo que apenas se contaba.

¿Cuándo se empezó a usar esta expresión en el idioma español? ¿Cómo se originó? ¿Formaba parte en su origen de una expresión más larga?

Comment: Por lo que veo en el CORDE, el uso actual empieza a finales del siglo XIX ([ejemplo](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=391&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=121117\022\C003O12112017220116583.1172.1168&desc={B}+{I}+menos+mal{|I},+en+todos+los+medios,+en+{I}CORDE+{|I}+{|B}{BR}&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto391)).

Comment: @pablodf76 entonces es mucho más reciente de lo que yo esperaba...

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser que se haya originado como una comparación de una situación mala con la actual, que no lo es tanto. Ya por los años 1254 se usa la expresión en un texto de astronomía (Judizios de las estrellas, 1254 - 1260, Anónimo) ([1](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=1&iniItem=0&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=131117%5C015%5CC003O13112017154012952.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20menos%20mal%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&marcas=0)):

> E quando Saturno fuere en quadradura de venus; significa abaxamiento & desprecio de parte de mugieres. & sera uazio de todo bien. & acaecer la todo mal. & mayor miente si Saturno fuere alçado sobre venus. Mas si venus fueren alçada sobre Saturno; es menos mal. & aura

También se puede ver en este otro ejemplo el paralelo con otras frases, lo que hace ver su construcción un poco más clara (*menos daño ... menos mal*):

> viva en poder de rey sin justicia que non que biva sin rey en guerra e en miedo; **menos dapño** viene al pueblo por la desmesura del rey que non les viene por desmesura de la guerra; **menos mal** viene al regno de la desmesura del rey que de la desmesura del pueblo.

Comment: Textos como el que comentas son relativamente habituales de encontrar, en los cuales la expresión "menos mal" se toma literalmente: "esto es menos mal que esto otro". En algún momento debió cambiar su significado literal para pasar a ser una interjección, usada con el propósito descrito en la pregunta: "menos mal que ha pasado esto".